# send a Model that is composed of other Model to the view and how to access the attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to send a Model to the view that is composed of another model.
Problem is i can't access the attributes of the composed Model in view.
The main Model is `FacadeController` and is composed of Admin Model.
the view accepts the Model `FacadeController` and then i can't access the attributes of the Admin Model like this. 
" `@Model.FacadeController.Admin` "

My semester projects depends on it please help.
Thank you.

```
# this is the Admin Model #
public class Admins
    {
        public int Admin_Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Image_path { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase Img { get; set; }

        //public AdoClass dataClass { get; set; }
        public Admins()
        {
            //dataClass = new AdoClass();
        }
    }
```

```
# this is the facadeController Model #
namespace EAProject.Models
{
    public class facadeController
    {
        public Admins Admin { get; set; }
        public facadeController()
        {
            Admin = new Admins();
        }
    }
}
```

```
#Controller #
public class Admin192_168Controller : Controller
    {
        public static facadeController facade;
        // GET: Admin192_168
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Admins currAdmin)
        {
            facade = new facadeController();
            facade.Admin = currAdmin;

            if (facade.LoginAdmin(facade.Admin))
            {
                currAdmin = facade.Admin;
                Session["AdminObj"] = currAdmin;
                if (Session["AdminObj"] == currAdmin)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Admin192_168");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Dashboard()
        {
            if (Session["AdminObj"] != null)
            {
                Admins ad = Session["AdminObj"] as Admins;
                facade.Admin = ad;
                return View(facade);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin192_168");
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Profile()
        {
            if (Session["AdminObj"] != null)
            {
                Admins ad = Session["AdminObj"] as Admins;
                return View(ad);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin192_168");
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public new ActionResult Profile(Admins ad)
        {
            if(Session["AdminObj"] != null){
                Admins temp = Session["AdminObj"] as Admins;
                ad.Admin_Id = temp.Admin_Id;
                facade.Admin = ad;
                string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(facade.Admin.Img.FileName);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(facade.Admin.Img.FileName);
                if(System.IO.File.Exists(temp.Image_path))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(temp.Image_path);
                }
                filename = filename + extension;
                facade.Admin.Image_path = "~/images/Admin/" + filename;
                filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/Admin/"), filename);
                Response.Write(Server.MapPath("~/images/Admin/" + "DefaultAdmin.PNG"));
                facade.Admin.Img.SaveAs(filename);
                if (facade.AdminEditProfile(facade.Admin))
                {
                    ad = facade.Admin;
                    Session["AdminObj"] = null;
                    if (Session["AdminObj"] == ad)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Admin192_168");
                    }
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin192_168");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Logout(bool op)
        {
            Session["AdminObj"] = null;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin192_168");
        }


        //This is to 
        /// <Add_the_Page_Dynamically>
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create_Pages()
        {
            if (Session["AdminObj"] != null)
            {
                Admins ad = Session["AdminObj"] as Admins;
                return View(ad);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin192_168");
        }
        /// </Add_the_Page_Dynamically>

    }
}
```

```
# Dashboard.cshtml view#
@model EAProject.Models.facadeController

<section class="section">
    <h1 class="section-header">
        <div>
            Dashboard
        </div>
    </h1>
    <div>
        @Html.Partial("Sajjad",Model.Admin);
    </div>
</section>
```

```
# Sajjad.cshtml  Partial View#
@model EAProject.Models.Admins

<h5>@Model.UserName</h5>
<h5>@Model.Email</h5>
```

Error and Stack trace

Server Error in '/' Application.
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'EAProject.Models.facadeController', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'EAProject.Models.Admins'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'EAProject.Models.facadeController', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'EAProject.Models.Admins'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'EAProject.Models.facadeController', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'EAProject.Models.Admins'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +175
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ConfigurePage(WebPageBase parentPage) +57
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.b__0(TextWriter writer) +218
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +80
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +63
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +237
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.b__4() +198
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9874041
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159

`@Model.Admin.Email` it gives error but attributes of admin model has all values but still error

Comment: From which page you've tried to access `@Model.FacadeController.Admin`?

Comment: And one more thing, You are sending condition model, for some criteria it redirects only page not model. In that case you won't get access to your model i guess and get exception

Comment: What is the route that throws error? Beyond that I can see some problems: if you first access Dashboard you'll get NullRefrenceException. Make sure having a static variable will not cause problem because it's shared by app domain.

Comment: @shahjahan   As my facadeController model is composed of another model that is admin  and this call ( `return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Admin192_168"); ` ) will redirect to this :
`[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Dashboard()
        {
            if (Session["AdminObj"] != null)
            {
                Admins ad = Session["AdminObj"] as Admins;
                facade.Admin = ad;
                return View(facade);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin192_168");
        }`

Comment: in Above Dashboard method this ( `return View(facade);` ) will return facade model to view and then in my it accepts :
 `@model EAProject.Models.facadeController`  
and i want to access the object of admin model that was composed in facadeController model and if i access this `@Html.Partial("Sajjad",Model.Admin);` way it gives error